# spark pi example runs but no worker resources allocated

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running the pi example. It executes fine and returning the result.

But, regarding the worker I just can see that is Alive, no resources used!
No Job Details filled, nothing.

I am running spark locally.

`start-master.sh -h 127.0.0.1`

`start-slave.sh spark://127.0.0.1:7077`

[image: master]

[image: worker]

Comment: You should pass your local master address in  spark-submit command `--master spark://127.0.0.1:7077`

Comment: @chlebek: Hmm!ok , it worked! So, everytime I want to execute a python file for example, I have to execute it through spark-submit, right? Otherwise, it won't run on the worker?

Comment: correct, also you can pass master address in code using `.setMaster(...)` and then run as python script

Comment: @chlebek:Ok, thanks! Make it an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass your local master address in spark-submit command `--master spark://127.0.0.1:7077` also you can pass master address in code using `.setMaster(...)` and then run as a python script.